# How to convert a string to integer in VHDL?

Tags: string, integer, type-conversion, vhdl

I am loading text data into a VHDL test bench and I want to convert input strings into integer values.

eg: "123" => 123

Can someone recommend a "best" way of converting strings to integers in VHDL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**readline** and **read** functions should achieve what you are looking for.

Basically:

1. Open your file
2. Use readline to get the next line from file into a line buffer
3. Use read to parse the line buffer to useful data
4. (Optional) convert the parsed value as necessary

---

Code Snippet:

```
library STD;
use std.textio.all;
...
variable File_Name         : string;
file my_file               : text; 
variable lineptr           : line;
variable temp              : integer;
...
file_open(my_file, File_Name, read_mode); -- open the file
readline(my_file, lineptr); -- put the next line of the file into a buffer
read(lineptr, temp); -- "parse" the line buffer to an integer
-- temp now contains the integer from the line in the file
...
```

Comment: That sir is a tasty answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of reference. It is also possible to convert a string to integer using the `'value` attribute:

```vhdl
variable str : string := "1234";
variable int : integer;
...

int := integer'value(str);
```

Depending on one's needs this may be more desirable than the `read()` procedure because it does not destructively alter the source string. It does, however, only work if the string is a valid integer literal with no surrounding characters other than whitespace.

```vhdl
variable ln  : line;
variable int : integer;
...

ln := new string'("  456   ");  -- Whitespace will be ignored
int := integer'value(ln.all); -- Doesn't consume contents of ln

ln := new string'("789_000 more text");
int := integer'value(ln.all); -- This will fail unlike read()
```

Comment: +1, but it is worth noting that neither option is well supported by synthesis tools. Vivado 2020.1 fails to synthesize either option. For synthesizable code, I just wrote a little parser that converts each digit using `character'pos(x(i)) - character'pos('0')`. And don't forget the minus sign.